# Glass materials for GLB/GLTF for use in WebAR

Tags: modeling, materials, transparency, glass, pbr

I am working on creating 3D models so that they can be used in WebAR. There are for sure a lot of restrictions on what nodes can be used. For example, I cannot use Glass BSDF since the supported file format (GLTF) is not exactly compatible. Currently I am using the following settings.
First one is referenced and the second one is mine coz the first one did not work in WebAR.

**1. Referenced PBR**
[image: refernced pbr cycle]

**2. Mine, because I am new to PBR and this is what my brain rattled up for the effect.**
[image: my pbr cycle]

In WebAR, the second approach is performing better than the first. the second one renders a translucent cube as it should. But I want a perfect transparent effect like a pyrex glass.

What I am trying to achieve is the following (looks like plastic, I know).

[image: plastic egg shaped orb containers]

Even transparent BSDF is not completely supported, so far only principal BSDF is supported is what I know about.

File: https://makerpark.jp/ar/aoihako/

Comment: I have ideas on how to create a similar material in Blender, but I have no idea what you can achieve in WebAR. Since it seems that Color Ramps, Mix Shader don't work so well, I guess you would have to build a new material in WebAR to achieve something that looks like the Blender version. But then it is not a question for this site as we are here to help with problems using Blender - not how to recreate Blender materials in other software.

Comment: Maybe my question came off wrong. I'm sorry, I completely agree it is better to do it in the WebAR but that is way more complicated. I have seen some people actually do such a thing in blender. Using only the Principled BSDF to make see through effects like my expected output. I just wanted to know how it can be done coz I did not understand anything when I looked at their approach

Comment: Problem is, this is a Blender site. There might be people who know WebAR, but I wouldn't rely on that. Saying what you want it to look like in WebAR gives us no hint as to what you need to achieve in Blender to get that, but trying to solve problems using Blender is what this site is about. As I said before, if you wanted to do something like that in Blender I might have some ideas, but knowing beforehand that I would need nodes which are not compatible to WebAR or glTF makes all efforts useless.

Comment: Can we assume you've worked through Blender's [GLTF documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html)? Insofar as this is a Blender problem, that would seem to be your first port of call. ( At a guess, it would be very handy to know what GLTF extensions are supported by your external application)

Comment: Yeah I understand your point @GordonBrinkmann . The only reason I mentioned WebAR was for the context and as far as I know (I've been through the documentation) and various video tutorials. All of them use a custom image texture by mapping the entire model into the image and then converting it to a desired material, the process I understand nothing of. 

So far I can only end up using p-BSDF and I'd appreciate understanding were I am going wrong. I am sorry if it sounds rude, I am not trying to be so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched around a bit and found the answer myself and I thought it'd be nice to post it here for other rookies like myself.

I ended up using Glossy BSDF and Diffuse BSDF with a mix shader pointing it to the surface of the output and the principle BSDF with an image texture (designed it to work like I want) and matched the alpha channel of the image texture to the p-BSDF. The p-BSDF goes to volume output.

In the mix shader for Glossy and Diffuse BSDF, my factor was basically the Fresnel IOR value, here it gets tricky as you need to know the exact IOR values. You can find majority of those values here [IOR Reference values](https://pixelandpoly.com/ior.html)

Lastly is the export format, for my requirement, GLTF worked the best, just working around a bit in the export options will help. If you are sending this file to reality convertor to get a USDZ file (for complicated models) that will work as well.